# JHipster Gateway is not routing the requests to the Microservices

Tags: amazon-web-services, jhipster, netflix-zuul, jhipster-registry

I deployed the JHipster Microservices architecture following the docs. Each component is in one AWS instance. I using version v5.3.4

I can see the Microservice and the Gateway registered on the Registry.

[image]

Also, the microservice is up and I can see the welcome page.

[image]

Finally, in the gateway the server is listed.

[image]

However, I when I try to see the Swagger documentation in the gateway or access the microservice via the gateway URL.

[image]

What can be possible missing?

Update::

I see no errors in any of the logs, but I see the following WARN:

```
2018-09-25 15:14:37.584  WARN 1601 --- [  restartedMain] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : No URLs will be polled as dynamic configuration sources.
```

Moreover, I see the following message many times. That puzzles me, why it logs this apparently every minute if I am not adding new endpoints.

```
2018-09-26 11:14:25.331  INFO 2319 --- [trap-executor-0] c.n.d.s.r.aws.ConfigClusterResolver      : Resolving eureka endpoints via configuration
```

Comment: Hi Gael, thanks for the prompt answer.

The most strange messages are:2018-09-25 15:14:37.584  WARN 1601 --- [  restartedMain] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : No URLs will be polled as dynamic configuration sources.

.m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.security.authentication.InsufficientAuthenticationException: Full authentication is required to access this resource]
2018-09-26 10:24:25.325  INFO 2319 --- [trap-executor-0] c.n.d.s.r.aws.ConfigClusterResolver      : Resolving eureka endpoints via configuration

Comment: Have you configured zuul routes in the application-prod.yml of your gateway? On registry are you using native or git configuration source ? In your config source have you created yaml files for your services and gateways? https://www.jhipster.tech/jhipster-registry/#spring-cloud-config

Comment: Hi Gael, 
1 - I didn't. My understanding it that the registry will be adding the routes. Should I add the routes 
2 -  I used the registry from Github releases.
3 - I am not sure. I have the application.yml and the boostrap.yml, my only change was pointing to the registry.

Comment: Gael, I used this command:

./jhipster-registry-<version>.war --spring.security.user.password=admin --jhipster.security.authentication.jwt.secret=secret-key --spring.cloud.config.server.composite[0].type=native --spring.cloud.config.server.composite[0].search-locations=file:./central-config

Comment: Based on the details (prod, swagger, microservices), I'm guessing it's related to this issue: https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/8328

Comment: Thanks Jon, I will try downgrading :(

Comment: @JonRuddell I tried downgrading to 5.0.2 without success :(. Do you think it can be related to a missing configuration like stated by Gael?

Comment: After reviewing all the configs, I am receiving : Resolving eureka endpoints via configuration
2018-09-28 21:17:40.468  WARN 45491 --- [ XNIO-2 task-24] o.s.c.n.z.filters.post.SendErrorFilter   : Error during filtering

com.netflix.zuul.exception.ZuulException: Forwarding error
        at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.handleException(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:189)
        at

Comment: @JonRuddell you were right. It was the same issue and the only thing I had to do was removing the compression of swagger :( such waste of time

Answer (score 1):

The answer for this problem is changing the parameter of compression on config/application-prod.yml

It should be:

server:
    compression:
        enabled: false